# How to dynamically change panelGroup using selectOneListBox and AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want to change the look of the menu based on the selected item.

how to get the value of selectonelistbox using managed bean?

Bean source:

```
    public void selectOneMenuListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Object newValue = (String) event.getNewValue(); 
    selectedMenu = newValue.toString();
}

public String getSelectedMenu() {
    return selectedMenu;
}

public void setSelectedMenu(String selectedMenu) {
    this.selectedMenu = selectedMenu;
}
```

Page:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <h:selectOneListbox id="katProduktu" valueChangeListener="#{produkt_KatBean.selectOneMenuListener}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{produkt_KatBean.produkt_KatAllList}"
            var="pk" itemLabel="#{pk.symbol}" itemValue="#{pk.id}"/>
        <f:ajax render="produktMenu" event="change" execute="@this" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="produktMenu">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==1}">
        Menu 1
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==2}">
        Menu 2
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==3}">
        Menu 3
    </h:panelGroup>     
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==4}">
        Manu 4
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `valueChangeListener`. It's the wrong tool for the job. Just bind the property to the `value` attribute of the menu component and let the `rendered` attribute intercept on that. This way you don't need a listener at all. Also your `rendered` comparisons won't work for strings. You should have used `== '1'` instead of `== 1` and so on, but this is plain clumsy, just make it `Long` (or `Integer`).

```html
<h:panelGroup id="panel">
    <h:selectOneListbox id="katProduktu" value="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{produkt_KatBean.produkt_KatAllList}"
            var="pk" itemLabel="#{pk.symbol}" itemValue="#{pk.id}"/>
        <f:ajax render="produktMenu" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="produktMenu">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==1}">
        Menu 1
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==2}">
        Menu 2
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==3}">
        Menu 3
    </h:panelGroup>     
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu==4}">
        Manu 4
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

With just

```
private Long selectedMenu; // Or Integer? Should be the same type as #{pk.id}.

// +getter +setter
```

*(note that I omitted the `event` and `execute` attributes of `<f:ajax>` as they represented the default values already)*

Comment: Exactly this code, copypasted into a completely blank page with just a `<h:form>`, works for me. Verify if you understood the answer well. Also try to elaborate "does not work" in developer's perspective instead of in enduser's perspective. Is the ajax request sent? Is the setter invoked? Is the getter invoked? Is the property type proper? Is the ajax response proper? No errors in server log? No errors in browser console? Etc.

Comment: I'm getting Java Exception: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @60,45 value="#{produkt_KatBean.selectedMenu}": Property 'selectedMenu' not writable on type pl.com.pir.beans.Produkt_KatBean

Comment: Well, that's rather self explaining. There's no setter method for that. Apparently you forgot to create or autogenerate the setter method.